# why does link inside indented p also indent

Tags: css, anchor, text-indent

The paragraph below is indented with css: `p + p {text-indent: 1.5em; margin-top: 0}`. The a:hover tags inside this paragraph also indent showing extra space on the left side of the link, but I don't understand why that happens. Why would paragraph indent also apply to the links inside the paragraph?

The simple fix I found is just to add `text-indent: 0;` to a:hover. Is that the best fix?

`<p>Due to the negative impacts to migratory and resident birds, the National Audubon Society has proposed a set of siting criteria for wind turbines (PDF Download: <a href="pdf/conservation/Responsible-Wind-Power-Wildlife.pdf"> Responsible Wind Power and Wildlife</a>). An <a href="#nas-ex">excerpt</a> from this publication is copied below. Wind energy information is also available on the Audubon website (<a href="https://www.audubon.org/news/wind-power-and-birds" target="_blank">Wind Power and Birds</a>).`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Thanks. I found the 'How to create a ... ' link most helpful as I had never heard of Stack Snippet before. I got Stack Snippet to work with my code but it didn't show the problem because I had already fixed the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The text-indent property is inherited when specified on a block element, which means it will affect inline-block descendant elements as well. When dealing with inline-block children, you may want to force them to text-indent: 0;
> – https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-indent/

Are you styling your `<p>` and `<a>` as block/inline-block elements?
Make a stack snippet so that we can see your code in action.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found that taking inline-block off the anchor tag worked as did the text-indent: 0. So I have the code working properly now. How do I give you credit for your answer?

Comment: Nice! You should be able to mark accept answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. You can see more info about that here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks again for helping me understand about Accept an Answer.